# How to detect if html finished rendering?

Tags: html, angular

With Angular2, I want to disable a button  while loading html and make it enable when finishing rendering. How can I detect when finishing rendering?

Comment: What HTML are you loading how?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the attribute `defer` in the `<script>` tag that loads your Angular code. This will ensure the code inside that script will be executed right after the rendering process is done. Have a look on this [example](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html)